# Measurement of ICE torque

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering, torque, power, combustion

I'm seeking a precise description of engine torque.

We talk about torque in terms of the twisting force that the piston exerts on the crankshaft with a radius equivalent of the rod throw.

Assume these two scenarios:

**Engine 1:** 6 cylinder, 2.5L diesel making 480 Nm torque

**Engine 2:** 4 cylinder, 2.0L diesel making 390 Nm torque

Cylinder volume on eng 1 is 2.5 / 6 = 0.416L

Cylinder volume on eng 2 is 2.0 / 4 = 0.5L

So its apparent that the cylindrical volume on the smaller displacement engine is larger.

How come the 6-cylinder engine produces more torque, instead of only smoothening out the performance due do less crank rotation per firing event?

I'm thinking that torque is measured with two crank rotations in mind.

Am I correct on this assumption, and if not - how is engine torque described precisely?

Comment: The torque is that which can be constantly applied to a brake on a heavy-ish flywheel. Historically, a strap brake was hung over the flywheel of the test load and weights were added. Thus "brake hp" was born. The torque specs today still reflect this original standard and are average values over the entire cycle.

Comment: Note that 480/2.5 = 192 Nm/L, 390/2.0 = 195 Nm/L. So on a displacement basis, the motors are very similar. Since the reported torque is the average, it is additive with respect to additional cylinders. The peak instantaneous torques can be much higher.

Comment: The “radius equivalent of the rod throw” is equal to zero twice of course.

Comment: @PhilSweet 'average' is the keyword I was looking for. So if I understood you correctly - more cylinders means more firing events that results in more consistent and higher averages of torque? So when you're saying the peak instantaneous torque can be much higher, is it then correct to deduct than in the moment of ignition, the torque will be very high but quickly wear off until the next firing event - making the reported torque land at an average?

Comment: @SolarMike What did you mean the radius is equal to zero twice?

Comment: Max torque is when the crank and the connecting rod are at a 90 degree angle, but when they are in line there is no torque applied and this happens at TDC and BDC...

Comment: To add to @SolarMike, the second variable is cylinder pressure at the different crank angles. This is controllable to a certain degree, which is good for keeping things light and long-lived, if not necessarily the best fuel efficiency. Still, fuel economy, emissions requirements, and economics all have an effect on how the cylinder builds pressure. Big diesels use a carefully calibrated injector duration to control peak pressures and mitigate torque ripple.

Comment: @PhilSweet Interesting addition! You're saying cylinder pressure is controllable to a certain extent. How? Are there any other ways of controlling the behaviour within a diesel's cylinder except injector operation and valve timing?

Comment: Cylinder swirl, fuel droplet size, the use of precombustion chambers and stratified combustion, combustion chamber geometry.

Comment: @PhilSweet definitely, but those are all (except maybe droplet size and swirl depending on flaps) factors outlined when designing the engine. It's not something that can be changed on-demand while running

Comment: @Erik if you are now asking about changing cylinder pressure "on demand while the engine is running" then that does not appear in your original question so you should consider a new one.